# ftp client with cloud storage for ftp credentials

Tags: ftp

I deal in many websites a lot and I have several computers. I always get frustrated when using FTP clients on windows or ubuntu because I need to type in the access details to the 30-40+ FTP accounts that I use.

Can anyone recommend a good FTP client that actually handles this situation well - the ideal situation is that they store the credentials somewhere online and I would have an account that allows me to download and use them immediately.

Free/Paid options are fine. Right now i'm using Filezilla, Notepad++ and Netbeans, and I haven't been able to find anything near the functionality that I need.

It's also hard to search for because if you search for the title of this question you get alot of people trying to FTP into cloud storage.

Thanks

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/209692/where-does-filezilla-server-store-its-users-data Get this file synced using the cloud service of your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very bad idea imho - which is probably why you haven't found anything. Storing credentials anywhere but your system will only make trouble later (unless they are encrypted server side as well).

What I do recommend however - setup a Linux box and "mount" the FTP servers using curlftps ( http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-mount-ftp-folder-to-local-directory-in-ubuntu.html ). And from there on your Linux box you can set one FTP account and each FTP server can then appear as a single folder. Or use whatever other remoting tech you want.

This way on whatever system you are on - you just FTP to one box and you have access to all the other FTP servers. Of course, you need to make sure that the linux box you do setup has adequate security.

Comment: Agreed about security, but I would assume any app which offers a solution would definitely be encrypted. As for your mounting folders, I do that in ubuntu. It's not a bad idea, but i am looking for a simpler solution. I actually already mount my ftp dirs in my ubuntu box. I SSH into that box, I will give what you say a try

Comment: It's dangerous to assume. Anything can happen - as a specific example Dropbox's auth system was broken for a couple of hours which allowed anyone to login to anyone's account with any password. Amazon's cloud service experienced a loss of data one time. I'm not saying you can't trust any service - just don't blindly trust them with your data, especially credentials to other client sites. I think something like this would be a self hosted solution - this way you can control the data access vs "in the cloud".